# difference between [self.property release] and [property release]

Tags: iphone

Can anyone tell me the difference between `[self.property release]` and `[property release]` . I am asking this because in one of the view controller in my application, I am doing `[self.property release]` and pushing this view controller in to the navigation stack, when I pop this view controller its showing the error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` but when i do `[property release]` everything is working fine...? Can any one tell me where I am going wrong. I am new to iPhone app development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[property release] sends the release message to the property instance variable and is almost certainly what you want to do.

[self.property release] sends the release message to the object returned by self.property. The result of this will depend on whether the property is defined as assign / copy / retain and so basically you are probably releasing a different object to the one that you think you are.

Comment: I would challenge this answer: the getter accessor is NOT returning a copy of the object, but the setter is who creates the copy. So sending release to the getter accessor would mean the same thing to sending a release to the ivar. I would call this answer incorrect ...

Answer (score 4):

The distinction is `self.myProperty` is an accessor method for the instance variable `myProperty`. Accessor methods are generated by `@synthesize`, or can be defined explicitly as

```
-(Type*) myProperty; 
-(void) setMyProperty:(Type*)p;
```

So, assuming you've defined the accessor as (the key is retain)

```
@property (retain) Type* myProperty;
```

then

```
[myProperty release]; 
myProperty = nil;
```

is equivalent to

```
self.myProperty = nil;
```

In general, it's good practice to set released objects to nil so that you don't accidentally try to use (or over release) them.

There is no good reason to call `[self.property release]`.