# Iphone Right way to set a property

Tags: iphone, memory-management

i have the following code in .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrayData;
```

And in the .m in method initWithNibName:

```
self.arrayData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Usuario:",@"Password:",nil];
```

is it right in order to call

```
[self.arrayData release]
```

safely in order to release the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct to call release on your property. The problem with it is, that you release your property, it will get deallocated, but you didn't set your pointer to nil, so somebody might send a message to your property and get a crash.

What you can do is the following:

1. self.arrayData = nil; ( which will release the previous saved instance, and set the property to nil)
2. [arrayData release]; arrayData = nil; (here you are accessing your ivar instead of your property; setting your ivar to nil is a precaution)
3. [self->arrayData release]; self->arrayData = nil (this is exactly the same as #2)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Setting an object in a property to nil also sends it a release? Wow.

Comment: okey it works, but what is the right way to set the arrayData:
self.arrayData  = [NSArray .... ] or
arrayData = [NSArray .... ]

thanks

Comment: since you property is retained, you can do: self.arrayData = [NSArray ...], or 2. arrayData = [[NSArray ...] retain]; . However using the self.arrayData is more safe (having in mind, that you might change the property declaration).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call:

```
[arrayData release]
```

Calling [self.arrayData release]; will not have the effect you want it to in either case.

If you're wondering why this is, check this question out: [difference between [self.property release] and [property release]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164216/difference-between-self-property-release-and-property-release)

Comment: The answer marked as correct for that question is incorrect. I've just commented on the answer the reason.

Answer (score 1):

A)
it is a bad idea to do this in your initializer (e.g., initWithNibName:bundle:)

```
self.arrayData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Usuario:",@"Password:",nil];
```

use this instead:

```
arrayData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Usuario:",@"Password:",nil];
```

you should not call these accessors (properties) in initializers or dealloc.

B)

> is it right in order to call
>
> [self.arrayData release]

no. in many cases (assuming you implement some of the properties you've declared), you may not be returned the the ivar. you may receive a copy, a placeholder object, or a subclass may have chosen to re-implement the accessors (as some examples). in these cases, it's easy to over-release or over-retain (resulting in evil stuff, like leaks and crashes).

this is typical:

```
self.arrayData = nil;
```

*unless* you are in `dealloc` of the object which declared the ivar:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [arrayData release], arrayData = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: why is better the option B? why cannot i call the accessors in initializers'

Comment: because the subclass' overrides may be called, listeners may be notified, dependencies may be created -- all this will happen when you've a partially initialized object. in dealloc, you may also 'resurrect' your object (or more precisely, its variables/state) when the accessors are called. at worst, it's undefined behavior (which is never good). at best, you'll probably end up over-retaining, over-releasing, or initializing something multiple times. if a subclass may allocate a new object (in init), then managing state becomes even more complicated. (cont)

Comment: finally, it's also a good idea to init and destroy the object correctly so your class may depend on and easily identify invalid states. that is, the class may easily determine if its state is valid or not, and rely on that promise/condition within its implementation.